# React Project Flipping Card, unable to achieve flipping functionality

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm pretty new to react. I'm following through with this tutorial at the moment but struggling to run it locally.

Tutorial -->
https://github.com/alexdevero/React-Flipping-Card-Tutorial

I've added the appropriate bootstrap headers in the index.html file and have integrated the React css-loader. I can run the react app locally but can't seem to acheive the flipping feature...

This is what the final app is meant to look like:

[Flipping Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0h0E.jpg)

This is what my local version looks like:
[Unstructured Flipping card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckiTa.jpg)

This is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>The Minimal React Webpack Babel Setup</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>
    <!-- <div id="app"></div> -->
    <div class="react-card"></div>
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
    </head>
</body>

</html>
```

Please give me guidance on how to acheive the flipping functionality.

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Since it will take a long time to read the tutorial I will simply explain how to achieve flipping a card.

first create a state property in the state.(I am using class Component)

```
this.state = { isFlipping: false };
```

then create a function to set the properties of the flipping: I set the state to true after 6 seconds.

```
animateCard() {
    this.cardAnimationInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(() => ({
        isFlipping: !this.state.isFlipping
      }));
    }, 6000);
  }
```

when component is loaded it call this function:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.animateCard();
  }
```

when we navigate to a different page we should stop flipping.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
//we make sure that cardAnimationInterval is defined otherwise clearInterval(this.cardAnimationInterval) would cause an error.
    this.cardAnimationInterval && clearInterval(this.cardAnimationInterval);
  }
```

this is the functionality of the flipping. now we need to set the css.
let's say our card is inside a div element

inside render(){}  write this:

```
const { isFlipping } = this.state;

 //if isFlipping true add "isFlipping" class otherwise nothing
 <div className={`flipper ${isFlipping ? "isFlipping" : ""}`}>
      <div className="front">{Place your card code here}</div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.flipper {
  //CSS transitions allows you to change property values smoothly, over a given duration.
  transition: 3s;
  //The transform-style property specifies how nested elements are rendered in 3D space.
  // This property must be used together with the transform property.
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

//initial state of .front class
.front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

//if isFlipping is true, change the initial value
.flipper.isFlipping {
  transform: rotateY(-360deg);
}
```